# How can I convert an audio channel inside an AVAssetTrack to PCM?

Tags: avfoundation, ios7, pcm

I'm trying to build an MTAudioProcessingTap that remixes the surround track of a video file. In order for that to work, I need to be able to convert each channel to PCM no matter what the source format is.

Do you guys know how can I identify each channel (figuring out what's left, center, surround left, etc) and attach a converter to each so it works inside my MTAudioprocessingTap?

Thank you so much. I can't find any info on this.

Comment: How did you go about getting all 6+ channels of audio into the MTAudioProcessingTap? I'm finding it mixes down to two (i.e., processingFormat->mChannelsPerFrame = 2 in the prepare callback).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out Core Audio takes care of everything with [Audio Converter Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).